# php including with the help of __dir__ doesnt work for me

Tags: php

I have a project

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefolder\
```

I am importing config.php in other files in other folders

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefolder\db\config.php
```

There is a file session.php whose path is:

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefolder\dashboard\includes\session.php
```

inside session.php I have a line

```
<?php 
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/db/config.php';
```

It doesnt work because when I echo `echo dirname(__DIR__);` inside the session.php file which is imported by `(C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefolder\dashboard\section1\index.php file)` it gives the path `C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefolder\dashboard`
so it tries to find the `config.php` file inside the dashboard folder and rightly gives the error `Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefolder\dashboard/db/config.php): failed to open stream:`

If i replace it with the below code then it works why because `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` just outputs `C:\xampp\htdocs\` no matter in which folder the file is in. I have to hard code `/sitefolder/` in this case. I am trying to find a better solution.

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sitefolder/db/config.php';
```

Comment: You would use relative paths with `dirname(__DIR__)`, so something like `require dirname(__DIR__) . '/../../db/config.php';`

Answer (score 0):

The `dirname(__DIR__)` will send you only. `"C:\xampp\htdocs\"` it will not include the `"sitefolder/"` into it. You must include `'sitesolder/'`. Like

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . 'sitefolder/db/config.php';
```

Try

```
echo dirname(__DIR__);
```

This will tell you what are you missing.